haskell package installation problem using GHCup "addDLL: mingw32 or dependencies not loaded. (Win32 error 126)" error message
After installing Sucessfully installing HaskellI open Windows PowerShell and try to run haskellThen I get this Error Message

PS C:\Users\Mee> ghci
GHCi, version 9.4.8: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
<command     line>: addDLL: mingw32 or dependencies not loaded. (Win32 error 126)

What should I do to fix it?
I have upgraded my Windows Power Shell, but the problem still persists.

You install mingw, to run a GCC compiler on Windows https://www.mingw-w64.org/

As the error says, Haskell depends on the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC) [wiki] to compile a program. You install Minimalistic GNU for Windows (MinGW) [wiki] such that the Haskell compiler has access to the GCC.
You can download MinGW here.

I had tried this, and the problem still persist. This install MinGW, not the missing Dll MinGW32. Btw thanks for your response

After try to reinstall GHCup, the problem fixed. Thanks.
